# Difference of BigDecimal as int?

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

I have two numbers, `1.4350` and `1.4300`. When I subtract them, instead of returning `0.0050`, I'm looking to get `50`. It also needs to work with `90.25` and `90.10`, returning `15`.

Comment: Is there a case where you substract 90.250 - 90.10?

Comment: Mathematically this doesn't make a lot of sense since 90.2500000 = 90.25.  Are they actual decimals or are they two different numbers joined with a decimal point?

Comment: Mathematically it is the case, but it's not for BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`BigDecimal.unscaledValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#unscaledValue%28%29). This will return what you want as a BigInteger.

```
// Two example numbers:
BigDecimal val0 = new BigDecimal("1.4350");
BigDecimal val1 = new BigDecimal("1.4300");


// This might be a method:

if (val0.scale() != val1.scale())
    throws new IllegalArgumentException("Scales are not the same!");

BigDecimal subtr = val0.subtract(val1);
System.out.println(subtr); // Prints 0.0050

BigInteger unscaled = subtr.unscaledValue();
System.out.println(unscaled); // Prints 50
```